# Rotation of the image formed by the extraordinary ray upon rotating the calcite crystal

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, geometric-optics, polarization, birefringence

Let a black spot is drawn on a piece of white paper. If we place a transparent calcite crystal on top of the paper, we observe two non-coincident images of the black spot. This is due to the phenomenon of birefringence or double refraction. One image is due to the ordinary ray and the other is due to the extraordinary ray. Now, the funny thing is that if the calcite crystal is slowly rotated, one image remains fixed while the other rotates around it. Can somebody explain this? I mean, why does one spot remain fixed while the other rotates?

Comment: Polarizer questions don’t fare too well here, in my limited experience. But the special relativity clock questions really do! Anyway, I hope this helped a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The scenario you describe is illustrated in the next two annotated photos I just did:

[image: Birefringence with calcite rhomb]

[image: Rotating rhomb rotates spots]

Rotating the calcite rhomb rotates the black spot on the paper under the crystal.

The optic axis of the calcite rhomb is oriented as shown in this annotated photo. The crystal is not birefringent for rays entering along the optic axis.

[image: Location of optic axis on calcite rhomb]

For a natural calcite crystal, it can sometimes be easy to find the optic axis by eye. This is shown in the next photo.

[image: Optic axis location on calcite crystal]

If a beam of light enters the calcite rhomb not along the optic axis, then the birefringence gives rise to both ordinary and extraordinary beams of light, which then exit the rhomb. This is shown in the next annotated photo. The 405 nm laser pointer light was attenuated by a filter and the beams that exit the rhomb cause the paper to fluoresce. This simply shows where the beams hit the paper.

[image: Showing two beams exit calcite rhomb]

**There is a great deal of information available in online and book references.**