# Double refraction in Calcite Crystal

Tags: optics, refraction, polarization

[image]

[image]

In the above text it is mentioned that the incident light ray travels along the principal section.But any ray which travels along the principal axis should not go through the double refraction. Then why the text says that the incident light ray split into two rays?

Comment: What do you mean by “principal axis”? The phrase is not used in the pasted text. The optic axis is different.

Comment: Perhaps see here to show where the optic axis is: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/733904/313612.

Comment: I apologize. By principal axis, I mean the "optic axis".

Comment: So your question is answered by yourself: any incident ray will experience the birefringence unless it is parallel with the optic axis.  Notice that the text says “A ray of light is incident on the face”. But the optic axis is not on any face, so no ray entering a face can be parallel to the optic axis.

Comment: Thanks for your help.